# OpenLayers 6 WCS time handling

Tags: openlayers, geoserver, wms, openlayers-6

I made this [codepen](https://codepen.io/StuckDuckF/pen/LYerbgg) to experiment with OpenLayers and a WCS layer. I understand there is no WCS support but I do manage to display it using an `Image` layer and an `ImageWMS` source since WCS is exposed using the same API as WMS. My question is this : Why is it that whgen I perform an `.updateParams({ RANGESUBSET: 'B1995' }` for example does my map object does not create a proper request like the initialization request which displays the data for the first step?

Comment: RANGESUBSET does not seem to be a valid parameter.  You get the same result even if you omit it.  Replacing it with TIME and removing the B from the years does show different images https://codepen.io/mike-000/pen/vYprZoy

Comment: Yes sir. you are absolutely right. I read this [documentation](https://eccc-msc.github.io/open-data/msc-geomet/web-services_en/#wcstime) and used to try to pass a `new Date()` object to the time parameter and was not getting anything. Would you like to move your answer to an answer so I can give you the rep you deserve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RANGESUBSET does not seem to be a valid parameter. You get the same result even if you omit it. Replacing it with TIME and removing the B from the years does show different images

```
let subset = ['1951','1952','1953','1954','1955','1995','1996','2000','2001','2004']

btn1.onclick = function () {
  map.getLayers().getArray()[1].getSource().updateParams({ TIME: subset[0] })
};

btn2.onclick = function () {
  map.getLayers().getArray()[1].getSource().updateParams({ TIME: subset[1] })
};

// etc.
```

https://codepen.io/mike-000/pen/vYprZoy